# In what way is the Grothendieck construction functorial?

Tags: category-theory

$\require{AMScd}$There's yet another thing I should know about the Grothendieck construction, and I don't.

One would like the "category of elements" construction to establish an equivalence of 2-categories between

1. The 2-category $[{\cal C}, {\sf Cat}]$ of pseudofunctors $F : {\cal C}\to {\sf Cat}$, pseudonatural transformations $\alpha : F \Rightarrow G$ and modifications $\Theta : \alpha \Rrightarrow \beta$.
2. The 2-category $\mathsf{opFib}/\cal C$ of opfibrations ${\cal E} \to {\cal C}$, morphisms of opfibrations (morphisms $H : {\cal E} \to {\cal F}$ in ${\sf Cat}/{\cal C}$ sending opcartesian morphisms to opcartesian morphisms) and natural transformations "fibered over $\cal C$".

It should be simple to define the correspondence $\int  : [{\cal C}, {\sf Cat}] \to \mathsf{opFib}/\cal C$ at the level of 1-cells, using the fact that $\int F$ is [the pullback](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+of+elements#definition)
$$\begin{CD}
\textstyle\int F @>T>> {\sf Cat}_* \\ 
@VSVV@VVUV \\ 
{\cal C} @>>F> {\sf Cat}
\end{CD}$$
Suppose given a pseudonatural transformation $\alpha : F \Rightarrow G$ between functors ${\cal C} \to {\sf Cat}$: one would like to induce a unique functor $H_\alpha : \int F \to \int G$ from a square
$$
\begin{CD}
\textstyle\int F @>T>> {\sf Cat}_* \\ 
@VSVV@VVUV \\ 
\cal C @>>G> \sf Cat
\end{CD}
$$ using the universal property of $\int G$. The problem is that in order to do this one wants a *commutative* square, whereas $\alpha$ gives just a noninvertible natural transformation $UT = FS\overset{\alpha S}\Rightarrow GS$ filling the square.

On the other hand, it's easy to define the functor $H_\alpha$ sending an object $(C, x)$ of $\int F$ to the object $(C, \alpha_Cx)$, so $H_\alpha$ "must" come from a universal property.

> Which one?

NB: I am aware that one can define $\int F$ also as a comma object; in that case, $\alpha$ will indeed induce the functor $H_\alpha$ I'm looking for. The question is thus how to deduce the existence of $H_\alpha$ *from the pullback definition only*.